# Align image at bottom of container

Tags: html, css, angularjs

How do I align an image to the bottom of a div?  I want the image denoted by ${addIcon} to be at the bottom of its container which is a dt.  I'm using AngularJS and Typescript.

```
 <td ng-repeat="slotContent in slotRow.Slots" class="${styles.calendarTableTD}">
             <div ng-repeat="booking in slotContent.Bookings">
              <span ng-show="booking.approved" class="${styles.calendarApprovedBooking}" ng-click="vm.editExistingBooking(booking)">{{booking.title}}</span>
              <span ng-show="booking.approved === false" class="${styles.calendarBooking}" ng-click="vm.editExistingBooking(booking)">{{booking.title}}</span>
             </div>
             <div style="cursor:pointer;" ng-show="slotContent.ShowAddIcon" ng-click="vm.newBooking(slotContent.SlotNumber, slotContent.SlotDate)">
                <img  src="${addIcon}"  style="height:20px; width: 20px;  align:vertical=bottom;">
             </div>
           </td>
```

Even with vertical-align=bottom; it stays in the middle.

Comment: pls add sample code

Comment: Check if the vertical-align show up when you inspect the element in your browser. Try putting !important behind, if that fixes it, there some other code overriding it so you should change that.

Comment: Please provide your `styles` object so that we can see what styles are applied.

Answer (score 0):

Giving the containing div 'display: flex' and 'align-items: flex-end' should do the trick.

```
<td ng-repeat="slotContent in slotRow.Slots" class="${styles.calendarTableTD}">
             <div ng-repeat="booking in slotContent.Bookings">
              <span ng-show="booking.approved" class="${styles.calendarApprovedBooking}" ng-click="vm.editExistingBooking(booking)">{{booking.title}}</span>
              <span ng-show="booking.approved === false" class="${styles.calendarBooking}" ng-click="vm.editExistingBooking(booking)">{{booking.title}}</span>
             </div>
             <div style="cursor:pointer; display: flex; align-items: flex-end;" ng-show="slotContent.ShowAddIcon" ng-click="vm.newBooking(slotContent.SlotNumber, slotContent.SlotDate)">
                <img  src="${addIcon}"  style="height:20px; width: 20px;  align:vertical=bottom;">
             </div>
           </td>
```

Comment: The icon goes to the bottom if the top div has text.  If it does not have text it remains in the middle.  I want it in the bottom in all cases.

Comment: Try wrapping both divs in a parent div and add the `style="cursor:pointer; display: flex; align-items: flex-end;"` part to that div. You might also want to set a height to that div, but without an example/fiddle that's a bit hard to tell...

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align: center;` if you are doing it inline.

```
<img  src="${addIcon}"  style="height:20px; width: 20px;  text-align: center;">
```

**EDIT:** 
Just get rid of all the `position: absolute;` and `align` styles affecting the image and do something like this example:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div+div {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

div img+img {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/64x64" alt="Example image">
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/64x64" alt="Example image">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/64x64" alt="Example image">
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't change vertical alignment.

Comment: I've put the css code in a scss file like this.  Could this be causing the problem?

@import '~@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core/dist/sass/SPFabricCore.scss';

.communityBoard {

 .align-icon {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
 }
 .align-icon img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right :0;
 }

}